# How to have an intermediate compile statement when generating a static library using cmake

Tags: cmake, llvm, static-libraries, llvm-ir, bitcode

I am successfully compiling, using clang, from source code to IR bitcode and generating a static library.  The problem I need to solve is that the IR refers to external global variables in their library internal global name.  I need to modify these internal global names to the external global name.  For example, in libc.a, in LLVM format:

```
@atoi = alias i32 (i8*), i32 (i8*)* @__GI_atoi

define hidden i32 @__GI_atoi(i8* nonnull) #0 {
  ...
  %4 call i64 @__GI_strtol(i8* %3, i8** null, i32 10) #2
  ...
}

declare hidden i64 @__GI_strtol(i8*, i8**, i32) #1
```

The `__GI_strtol` is external to the `atoi` module, but is internal to the `libc.a` archive.  The `strtol` module has a `@strtol = alias ... @__GI_strtol` definition and a `hidden` function called `GI_strtol`.

What I need to do is when compiling the source files (`atoi.c` in the above example), I need to do the following:

1. Compile the source file to `.ll` (LLVM) format.
2. Convert all `declare hidden`s that do **not** have an associated `alias` statement, to their external global value (basically, `hidden` --> `dso_local` and `__GI_*` to just `*`).
3. Convert the resulting `.ll` file to its IR bitcode (`.bc`) equivalent.
4. Insert the `.bc` file into the `libc.a` archive.

Is this possible?

I have a number of `add_custom_target`s and `add_custom_command`s in the CMake file, but none when compiling from `.c` to `.bc`.

If this were a `make` build, I'd simply add definitions to compile from `.c` to `.ll` and `.ll` to `.bc`, and in the last stage perform the changes indicated above.

I expect to be able to perform the above steps in the most efficient way possible using CMake.  I'd like to be able to do it without having to have, literally, 1000s of `add_custom_command/target`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to be able to do the conversion as part of the compilation.  So, I used `add_custom_command` with a `POST_LINK` on the archive itself.  Then I process each entry in the archive, doing the required conversion, and then updating the archive.

It is a sort of `get a bigger hammer` solution, but it works and does not add 100s of custom targets.